# Python, a decorator as an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I want to make an decorator which will take an another decorator function, as an argument.

And an decorator will do additional work.

```
def raise_error(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('hello from decorator')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@raise_error
def hello():
    return 'Hellom from function'


print(hello())
```

Technically, I can to write an decorator which will be take, raise_error decorator, and do some additional flow, inside the `raise_error` decorator?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility to have func as param to decorator.

```
def raise_error(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        test_func = getattr(func, 'tester', None)
        test_func()
        print('Hello from decorator')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def test():
    print('Hello from test')


def hello():
    print('Hello from function')
    return 'Hello from function'
hello.tester = test


decorated_hello = raise_error(hello)
decorated_hello()
```

Result:

```
Hello from test
Hello from decorator
Hello from function
```

Comment: Thank you, it's actually what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about multiple decorators?

Like this

```
def raise_error(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('hello from decorator')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def foo(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('bar')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@foo
@raise_error
def hello():
    return 'Hello from function'


print(hello())
```

Related question: [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators)